# how to call stored procedures in hibernate with date parameters?

Tags: java, hibernate

**MyController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ohlc",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<OhlcResponse> getOhlc(@RequestBody OhlcRequest ohlcRequest) {

    List<OhlcResponse> ohlc = ohlcService.getOhlc(ohlcRequest);
    return ohlc;
}
```

**OhlcDaoImpl.java**

```
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
            "CALL uspGetOhlcData(:stockCode,:fromDate,:toDate)")
            .addEntity(OhlcResponse.class)
            .setParameter("stockCode", ohlcRequest.getStockSymbol())
            .setParameter("fromDate",ohlcRequest.getFromDate())
            .setParameter("toDate", ohlcRequest.getToDate());


        List<OhlcResponse> list = query.list();

        return list;
}
```

**OhlcResponse.java**

```
public class OhlcResponse {

private int Id;

private BigDecimal MaxPrice;
private BigDecimal MinPrice;
private BigDecimal PreviousClosingPrice;
private BigDecimal ClosingPrice;

public BigDecimal getMaxPrice() {
    return MaxPrice;
}

public void setMaxPrice(BigDecimal maxPrice) {
    MaxPrice = maxPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getMinPrice() {
    return MinPrice;
}

public void setMinPrice(BigDecimal minPrice) {
    MinPrice = minPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getPreviousClosingPrice() {
    return PreviousClosingPrice;
}

public void setPreviousClosingPrice(BigDecimal previousClosingPrice) {
    PreviousClosingPrice = previousClosingPrice;
}

public BigDecimal getClosingPrice() {
    return ClosingPrice;
}

public void setClosingPrice(BigDecimal closingPrice) {
    ClosingPrice = closingPrice;
}
```

**Stored Procedure: uspGetOhlcData**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetOhlcData 
@StockSymbol varchar(50),   
@fromDate date,
@toDate date   
AS
BEGIN

SELECT  spd.ClosingPrice, spd.PreviousClosingPrice, spd.MinPrice,  spd.MaxPrice
FROM StockPriceDetl spd
inner join Stock stk on stk.Id = spd.StockId
inner join StockPriceMast spm on spm.Id = spd.MastId
WHERE stk.StockSymbol= @StockSymbol AND spm.TranDate Between @fromDate and     @toDate  
END
GO
```

as you can see my stored procedure returns maxprice, minprice, previousClosingPrice and ClosingPrice. i want to return those 4 data in json form binding them into ohlcResponse class.

the error i am currently getting is incorrect syntax near @PO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For syntax errors, your request and response seems ok,

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
               "CALL uspGetOhlcData(:stockCode,:fromDate,:toDate)")

You are using this query, and referring it the same in stored procedure as Symbol StockSymbol.
Try using stockCode here in Stored Procedure: uspGetOhlcData

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetOhlcData 
@stockCode varchar(50),   
@fromDate date,
@toDate date   
AS
BEGIN

SELECT  spd.ClosingPrice, spd.PreviousClosingPrice, spd.MinPrice,  spd.MaxPrice
FROM StockPriceDetl spd
inner join Stock stk on stk.Id = spd.StockId
inner join StockPriceMast spm on spm.Id = spd.MastId
WHERE stk.StockSymbol= @stockCode AND spm.TranDate Between @fromDate and     @toDate  
END
GO
```

Comment: thank you for quick response. now it says

 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.infodev.models.OhlcResponse

Comment: Well you have to annotate the `OhlcResponse` class with `@Entity` or list it in your xml mapping (depending on whichever method you're using).